# How to upload symbol files for crash report from my own code in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash-log

I want to crate a crash reporter like firebase in Objective-C but I don't know how to upload symbol files on my server. Please help me guys to symbolicate crash report.

I don't know how to write code for it.

Comment: [Crashlytics » Logged Errors](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/logged-errors.html) might be useful for what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I am using **PLCrashReporter** and I am able to get crash Logs but I want to get **file name**, **Method/Function Name** and **Line Number** where crash occurred.How can I get these details. I've also **symbolicated** crash logs using **PLCrashReportTextFormatter** but I want these details separately from **crashReport**

Answer (score 1):

Add this line into didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaughtExceptionHandlingMethod);
```

And add this method. This will get the stack trace from exception and write it on the txt file.

```
-(void) uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *exception){

NSLog(@"On uncaught Exception Handling method");
//NSString *content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[exception callStackSymbols]];
//NSLog(@"Stack trace : %@",content);

// To write the stack trace into txt file.
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *logPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myowncrashreport.txt"];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[exception callStackSymbols]];
[content writeToFile:logPath atomically:YES encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
freopen([logPath cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],"a+",stderr);
}
```

Comment: I am using **PLCrashReporter** and I am able to get crash Logs but I want to get **file name**, **Method/Function Name** and **Line Number** where crash occurred.How can I get these details. I've also **symbolicated** crash logs using **PLCrashReportTextFormatter** but I want these details separately from **crashReport**

Comment: Hi Ashraf, NSLog(@"Line:%d, Method: %s", LINE, __FUNCTION__); try this line to get the line number and method name from the exception. Its working in Try catch block.